# Сравнение строк-дат

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня задача, сделать функцию, которая будет работать следующим образом: пользователь вводит желаемый город, свой город, и дату в формате 12-12-2020, с целью уехать. Города доступны те, которые есть в списке. Я в функции сравнивал первые 3 буквы, на случай неправильного окончания при вводе. Далее у каждого рейса должно быть расписание, к примеру москва-анапа 2 раза в месяц 15 и 30 числа, ростов-анапа 4 раза в месяц и т.д. И задачей функции является выдать ближайшие 5 рейсов к дате(после нее), которую ввел пользователь. Вот в этом моменте не пойму, как лучше реализовать. Полагаю, нужно сделать списки на 2-3 месяца к каждому городу, наполнить датами и сравнивать. Но не пойму как реализовать сравнение.

```
target_cities = ("москва","ростов","тверь","казань", "самара")
current_cities = ("анапа", "грозный", "екатеринбург", "оренбург", "коломна")
target_1 = 'мос'
target_2 = 'ана'
date = '12-12-2020'
def dispatch(city1,city2):
    for town1 in target_cities:
        if city1[0:2] == town1[0:2]:
            print(town1)
    for town2 in current_cities:
        if city2[0:2] == town2[0:2]:
            print(town2)
    mos_ana = ['15-12-2020','30-12-2020','15-01-2020','30-01-2020','15-02-2020','30-02-2020','15-03-2020','30-03-2020']
dispatch(town1=target_1,town2=target_2)
```

UPD
Подскажите, почему таким образом не работает сравнение?

```
date1 = '02-16-2021'
mos_ana = ['12-11-2020','12-30-2020','01-15-2021','01-30-2021','02-15-2021','02-30-2021','03-15-2021','03-30-2021']
for date in mos_ana:
    first = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y')
    second = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%m-%d-%Y')
    if first > second:
        print(second)
```

```
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Происходит такая ошибка. пробовал год вперед поставить, но тоже не сработало

Comment: Такие задачи лучше решать через базы данных

Comment: Ошибка из-за того, что в феврале не бывает 30 дней. :)

Comment: @SergBocharov не обязательно такие условия через БД делать. В условии все рейсы поддаются вычислению, их даже хранить не надо, а генерить списки на ходу можно.  Даже если будут даты не цикличные, то эти данные не на столько большие, их запросто можно в csv хранить, например. Ну а pandas вполне может даже запросы формировать по данным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать объект диспетчер, который хранит рейсы и их даты в словаре вида:

```
{('москва', 'анапа'): [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 15, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 30, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 0, 0),
                       datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 30, 0, 0)]}
```

**ключ** - кортеж с пунктами отправки/прибытия.
**значение** - отсортированный список с датами отправления для данного рейса.

По запросу диспетчер будет выдавать ближайшие даты.

```
class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.departures = {}

    def set_journey_departure_dates(self, journey, dates):
        self.departures[journey] = sorted(map(self.date_to_datetime, dates))

    def search_nearest_departures(self, journey, target_date, number_of_departures):
        target_date = self.date_to_datetime(target_date)

        idx = 0
        for idx, departure_date in enumerate(self.departures[journey]):
            if departure_date > target_date:
                break

        return self.departures[journey][idx:idx + number_of_departures]

    @staticmethod
    def date_to_datetime(date):
        return datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

**Тестирование**

```
from pprint import pprint

dispatcher = Dispatcher()

target_journey = ('москва', 'анапа')
target_journey_departure_dates = [
                                    '15-12-2020',
                                    '30-12-2020',
                                    '15-01-2020',
                                    '30-01-2020',
                                    '15-02-2020',
                                    '29-02-2020',
                                    '15-03-2020',
                                    '30-03-2020'
                                  ]

dispatcher.set_journey_departure_dates(target_journey, target_journey_departure_dates)

target_date = "12-12-2020"
number_of_departures = 4
pprint(dispatcher.search_nearest_departures(target_journey, target_date, number_of_departures), width=20)

print()

target_date = "12-01-2020"
number_of_departures = 4
pprint(dispatcher.search_nearest_departures(target_journey, target_date, number_of_departures), width=20)
```

**Результат**

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 30, 0, 0)]

[datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 0, 0)]
```